# How to fetch category products with all attributes in REST api

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, rest-api, product-collection

There are categories in our store like featured and promotional. I fetch them in frontend by using there category id.Now I have fetch them through REST api.I made all the oauth configuration and set consumer successfully. So I have registered my module and added api2.xml. Added endpoint as `/homepage/featured` for featured products.

In V1.php

```
protected function _retrieveCollection() {
    $maincategory = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/category' )->load ( 192 )->getProductCollection ();
    return $maincategory;
}
```

It is returning the product's but with less attributes.

[image]

How can I fetch all the product's attribute's from any category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `addAttributeToSelect(*)`

```
protected function _retrieveCollection() {
    $maincategory = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/category' )->load ( 192 )->getProductCollection ()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $maincategory;
}
```